# ant javascript getProperty xml

Tags: javascript, xml, ant, junit

I have a file rapport.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<testsuites name="COMPTES" tests="8" time="7" timestamp="2014-07-01T17-20-07" failures="8" errors="0">
    <testsuite name="100" tests="4" failures="4" errors="0" time="7">
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.100" name="TEST1" time="1">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileNotExist">
                File No matches
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.100" name="TEST2" time="2">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileUsed">
                Data set in use
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.100" name="TEST3" time="3">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileNotExist">
                File No matches
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.100" name="TEST4" time="3">
            <failure message="File abended" type="abended">
                File abended
            </failure>
        </testcase>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="120" tests="4" failures="4" errors="0" time="7">
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.120" name="TEST1" time="1">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileUsed">
                Data set in use
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.120" name="TEST2" time="2">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileNotExist">
                File No matches
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.120" name="TEST3" time="3">
            <failure message="File abended" type="abended">
                File abended
            </failure>
        </testcase>
        <testcase classname="Script.COMPTES.120" name="TEST4" time="3">
            <failure message="Not exist file or used" type="fileUsed">
                Data set in use
            </failure>
        </testcase>     
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

In build.xml I use a javascript tag but I can not access the number of "testcase" with "testsuite"

```
<script language="javascript">
    <![CDATA[ 
    var testsuites = project.getProperty('testsuites.name');

      var testsuite = project.getProperty('testsuites.testsuite').split(',');
      var testcase = testsuite[0].getProperty('testsuites.testsuite.testcase').split(',');
      println('testcase ' + testcase.length);

    project.setProperty('testsuites ', testsuites );
    ]]>
</script>
```

I would like to retrieve the number of "testcase" whose failure is not exist file, or abended file used for each "testsuite".

I would like to display :

```
[script] testsuite : 100 
[script] count file used : 1
[script] count file no matches : 2
[script] count file abended : 1
[script] testsuite : 120
[script] count file used : 2
[script] count file no matches : 1
[script] count file abended : 1
```

Can you help me please, thank you

Comment: The most appropriate tool for this would probably be [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) for Ant.

Comment: @Rebse do you have a solution for this problem ?

Comment: @CAustin In build.xml I use a javascript tag but I can not access the number of "testcase" with "testsuite" I do not use Xmltask

Comment: You should use the suitable tool and switch to xmltask ! Don't use a sledgehammer when you need a screwdriver ;) see my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**-- EDIT, straightforward solution with xmltask --**

When using [xmltask](http://www.oopsconsultancy.com/software/xmltask/) it's a piece of cake :

```
<project>

  <!-- Import XMLTask -->
  <taskdef name="xmltask" classname="com.oopsconsultancy.xmltask.ant.XmlTask"/>

 <xmltask source="rapport.xml">
  <call path="//testsuite">
   <param name="testsuite" path="@name"/>
   <param name="fileused" path="count(testcase/failure[@type='fileUsed'])"/>
   <param name="filenomatch" path="count(testcase/failure[@type='fileNotExist'])"/>
   <param name="fileabended" path="count(testcase/failure[@type='abended'])"/>
  <actions>
   <echo>
    testsuite : @{testsuite}
    count file used : @{fileused}
    count file no matches : @{filenomatch}
    count file abended : @{fileabended}</echo>
  </actions>
  </call>
 </xmltask>

</project>
```

output :

```
[echo]     testsuite : 100
[echo]     count file used : 1
[echo]     count file no matches : 2
[echo]     count file abended : 1
[echo]     testsuite : 120
[echo]     count file used : 2
[echo]     count file no matches : 1
[echo]     count file abended : 1
```

Otherwise it get's complicated, a quick shot using script task with javascript :

```
<project>

 <xmlproperty file="rapport.xml" collapseattributes="true"/>

<!--
<xmlproperty file="rapport.xml" collapseattributes="true"/>
<echoproperties prefix="testsuites"/>

[echoproperties] testsuites.errors=0
[echoproperties] testsuites.failures=6
[echoproperties] testsuites.name=COMPTES
[echoproperties] testsuites.tests=6
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.errors=0,0
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.failures=6,6
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.name=100,120
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.classname=Script.COMPTES.100,Script.COMPTES.100,Script.COMPTES.100,Script.COMPTES.100,Script.COMPTES.120,Script.COMPTES.120,Script.COMPTES.120,Script.COMPTES.120
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.failure=File No matches,Data set in use,File No matches,File abended,Data set in use,File No matches,File abended,Data set in use
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.failure.message=Not exist file or used,Not exist file or used,Not exist file or used,File abended,Not exist file or used,Not exist file or used,File abended,Not exist file or used
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.failure.type=fileNotExist,fileUsed,fileNotExist,abended,fileUsed,fileNotExist,abended,fileUsed
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.name=TEST1,TEST2,TEST3,TEST4,TEST1,TEST2,TEST3,TEST4
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.testcase.time=1,2,3,3,1,2,3,3
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.tests=6,6
[echoproperties] testsuites.testsuite.time=7,7
[echoproperties] testsuites.time=7
[echoproperties] testsuites.timestamp=2014-07-01T17-20-07

-->

<script language="javascript">
importPackage(java.util);

var testsuites = project.getProperty('testsuites.testsuite.name').split(',');

var testcases = project.getProperty('testsuites.testsuite.testcase.classname');
var testcaseclasses = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(testcases.split(',')));
// determine how many different TestClasses
var testsunique = new ArrayList(new HashSet(testcaseclasses));
Collections.sort(testsunique);

var failures = project.getProperty('testsuites.testsuite.testcase.failure.type');
var failuretypes = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(failures.split(',')));
// determine how many different Failuretypes
var failuresunique = new ArrayList(new HashSet(failuretypes));
Collections.sort(failuresunique);


for (var i=0; i &lt; testsuites.length; i++) {
 println('testsuite : ' + testsuites[i]);
 for (var j=0; j &lt; failuresunique.size(); j++) {
  println ('count ' + failuresunique.get(j) + ' : ' + Collections.frequency(failuretypes.subList(0,Collections.frequency(testcaseclasses, testsunique.get(i))), failuresunique.get(j)));
 }
 failuretypes.remove(failuretypes.subList(0,Collections.frequency(testcaseclasses, testsunique.get(i))).clear());
}
</script>

</project>
```

output :

```
[script] testsuite : 100
[script] count abended : 1
[script] count fileNotExist : 2
[script] count fileUsed : 1
[script] testsuite : 120
[script] count abended : 1
[script] count fileNotExist : 1
[script] count fileUsed : 2
```

Comment: Thank you @Rebse very much you have helped me and I thank you :) 
Now I will try to understand the mechanism because I have to write my internship report and explain how it works  
To solve this problem I was trying to use the "switch case" on loop "for" but it did not work 
Thank you again you take me a thorn in the foot.

Comment: Hello @Rebse, I would like to know what methods we can use in the path attribute of the param tag are. In this example you use count: <param name="fileabended" path="count(testcase/failure[@type='abended'])"/>

Comment: XPath expressions => something like 'SQL for xml', the xmltask path attribute understand XPath 1.0, some good xpath tutorials : http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General_ger/examples.html , http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/

Answer (score 0):

it looks like there's a bug in your javascript.
It should be:

```
var testcase = testsuite[0].getProperty('testcase').split(',');
```